# Find the Intervals when $\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi x^2\right)$ is positive.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am looking for a general solution, not in any restricted domain.

Comment: For what intervals are $\cos(z)$ positive?

Comment: I am having difficult finding that too, I can tell for $[0, 2\pi]$

Comment: Ok in which intervals at $[0,2\pi]$ $\cos(z)>0$

Comment: Note that $\cos(z)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. If $\cos(z) > 0$ then $\cos(z + 2\pi n) > 0$ for all integers $n$.

Answer (score 3):

As $\displaystyle\cos x>0$ in $\displaystyle\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right),$

we need $\displaystyle2n\pi-\frac\pi2<\frac{\pi x^2}2<2n\pi+\frac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\iff4n-1<x^2<4n+1$$

---

The other way is even cleaner

As $\displaystyle\cos x<0$ in $\displaystyle\left(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right),$

$\displaystyle\cos x<0$ in

$\displaystyle2m\pi+\frac\pi2<\frac{\pi x^2}2<2m\pi+\frac{3\pi}2$ where $m$ is any integer

$\displaystyle\iff4m+1<x^2<4m+3$

Comment: Why do $x$ have to be an integer? The second to last implication is not correct.

Comment: looks good, thanks a lot

Comment: I agree with Winther, lab screwed it after $4n-1 < x^2 < 4n+1$, you can(should) just leave it there

Comment: @Winther, Thanks for your observation. I was thinking about the rectification while dining

Comment: @Holycow, Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Before solving $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2\right) \geq 0$ let's look at $\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}x^2\right) = 0$.

We know that $\cos t = 0$ iff $t = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$ ($k$ integer).

So $\frac{\pi}{2}x^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k \Rightarrow x^2 = 1 + 2k \Rightarrow x = \sqrt{2k+1}$.

So the intervals will be of the form $\left(\sqrt{2k+1},\sqrt{2k+3}\right)$.

Now we just have to check if $k$ must be odd or even. A simple check will show that for $x\in (1,\sqrt{3})$ we get a negative function, so $k$ must be even.

Comment: Jepp, but you forgot the negative intervals $x<0$

Comment: Just take the negative square root ;)
$(-\sqrt{2k+3},-\sqrt{2k+1})$